# R: how can i use lapply to plot multiple graphs with different numerical variables as y and different categorial ones as fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I have a dataset with numerical and categorial variables, i want to produce a series of boxplots of the numerical variables with the fill being the categorical ones.

Heres an example dataframe

```
data <- data.frame(numA= c(50, 47, 49, 47, 46, 48, 45),
                numB= c(625,  546,  590,  690,  641,  526, 600),
                numC=c(38.246, 26.025, 23.999, 62.294, 12.149, 23.738, 68.664),
                catA = c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                catB = c("dd","ee","ff","dd","ee","ff","dd"))
```

then i find which variable is category and which is numerical

```
nums <- unlist(lapply(data, is.numeric), use.names = T)
cat <- colnames(data[,!nums])
num <- colnames(data[, nums])
```

finally I write the plotting function

```
boxplot_num_x_cat <- function(num, cat) {
  ggplot(data=data, aes(y=data[,num], fill=data[,cat]))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(y =num, x = cat, fill = cat,
       title = paste("boxplot of", num, "according to", cat ))
}
```

if run the function

```
boxplot_num_x_cat("numA","catA")
```

it works, the same as running the lapply with only one element of the vector cat:

```
lapply(num, boxplot_num_x_cat,cat[[1]])
```

however i want to have plot with all the combinations of num and cat, possibly stored in the same list, how cai i make that work? I tried with

```
lapply(num, boxplot_num_x_cat,cat)
```

and it gaves me error cause i think it maps the whole vector cat into the aes of the plot and not only its 1st element. I'm sure I'm missing something in the use of lapply cause i'm fairly new to the tidyverse approach.

Thank you a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of the plots as follows:

```
plots = apply(expand.grid(cat,num), 1, \(r) boxplot_num_x_cat(r[2], r[1]))
```

If you want to plot that list, you can do this:

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs=plots)
```

As an aside, as your `boxplot_num_x_cat()` function is currently written, it is ignoring the `data=data` parameter.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. Can I ask for a brief explaination of what the first line of code do? As a beginner is not very clear to me

Comment: sure,. You can use `expand.grid` to create a frame that contains one row for each combination of `cat` and `num` (i.e. a 6-row data frame).  I then use `apply()` to apply a function on each row of that frame.. `apply()` can be done rowwise or colwise; use `1` in the second parameter to indicate rowwise.  The third param of `apply()` is the function you want to be run on each row (or column).  `\(r)` is shorthand for `function(r)` (since R 4.1).

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to use [`tidyr::crossing`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/expand.html):

```
rslt <- 
tidyr::crossing(num, cat) |> 
  dplyr::rowwise() |> 
  dplyr::mutate(plots = boxplot_num_x_cat(num, cat) |> list())

rslt

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  num   cat   plots 
  <chr> <chr> <list>
1 numA  catA  <gg>  
2 numA  catB  <gg>  
3 numB  catA  <gg>  
4 numB  catB  <gg>  
5 numC  catA  <gg>  
6 numC  catB  <gg> 

rslt$plots[[2]]
```

[image]

Comment: @Appo_55 You are welcome and welcome to stackoverflow. It is common here to upvote and/or accept answers should one finds them useful. You can read a bit from here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20vote%20up,arrow%20to%20undo%20a%20downvote.